# Do something if 'div' is display = none or != none

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox (checked = false) and a div ( display = none) when

- I click into checkbox - div will be display, checked = true
- And click againt - div will be set display = none, checked = false.

When I click into checkbox, I want to check if div is display ( set checked == true), show "slidingDiv show" and click into checkbox againt - div is display = none ( set checked == false), show "slidingDiv hidden".

```
function ShowHide() {
            if ($("#slidingDiv").css(":display") == "none") {
                alert("slidingDiv display none.");
            }
            else {
                alert("slidingDiv show.");
            }

            $("#slidingDiv").animate({ "height": "toggle" }, { duration: 400 });
        }
```

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a css class to set the div visible or hidden.

For instance - if you want it to be hidden by default you set

```
<div id="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
```

where class "mydiv" has display:none;
To show it you add class "visible" which has display:block;

```
if ($("#mydiv").hasClass("visible")) {
  alert('hide');
  $("#mydiv").removeClass('visible');

} else {
  alert('show');      
  $("#mydiv").addClass('visible');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use this to get the display attribute:

```
var display = $("#slidingDiv").css("display"); //note that there is no leading colon (':')
```

Alternatively you can use a simpler check:

```
if ($("#slidingDiv").is(":visible")) {
  alert("slidingDiv show.");
} else {
  alert("slidingDiv display none.");
}
```

Comment: oh my div was set default: display:none, when I click into checkbox, it show "slidingDiv show.". I click it againt, it show "slidingDiv show." againt.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use this

```
function showHide()
{
  if($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked'))
  {
    $("#mydiv").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#mydiv").hide();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Briganti/RDq9j/

Have fun :)